# Kinect V1 calibration with OpenCv and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, camera-calibration

I am working on a project with: openCv, C++, and Kinect v1 and I am using the 3rd dimension in my work but the problem is that the kinect needs to be calibrated and I didn't find a way to do it simply ( especially that I don't have much time ) .

Is there any simple way to calibrate the kinect ? I really need it  desperately.

PS: I already tried this code https://github.com/devkicks/OpenCVKinect it works just fine but when I use the openCv function: findCountour() I get errors with vectors.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by calibration. For color or infrared intrinsic parameters, this is the usual [camera calibration procedure](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/). For extrinsic calibration, see stereo calibration. You can also refer to similar topics in the [ROS community](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/ExtrinsicCalibration). Another [pointer](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will do more research about the setero Calibration